# about Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.8.0.2131:sonar (default-cli)

Tags: sonarqube, gitlab-ci

**Now I am building the integration between Gitlab-CI/CD and SonarQube, but now I cannot push it to the SonarQube server through CI for help！**

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.8.0.2131:sonar (default-cli) on project jeecg-boot-parent: Your project contains .java files, please provide compiled classes with sonar.java.binaries property, or exclude them from the analysis with sonar.exclusions property. -> [Help 1]

Sonarqube version 8.1

Comment: As the message says: you need to build your project first before running `sonar` target.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do sonar analysis of maven project, you need to first  compile the project, and provide the path to compiled bytecode files in `sonar.java.binaries` (As this is the mandatory parameter.

You can run the sonar analysis using the below command:

```
mvn clean install sonar:sonar -Dsonar.java.binaries=**/*.java
```

More reference: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/languages/java/